# Что не так с регулярным выражением

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо из заданной строки выделить все адреса электронной почты с помощью регулярного выражения. Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::string emails = "awlefla aaa@gmail.ru adlf111 2 * ed@ggg.er fgdfgd1gd141";
    std::regex reg2("[a-z0-9_][a-z0-9_\.-]*[a-z0-9_]@([a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9_-]*[a-z0-9]\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,}");
    std::smatch matches;
    while (std::regex_search(emails, matches, reg2)) {
        std::cout << matches[0] << "\n";
        emails = matches.suffix().str();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Выдает:

> aaa@gmail.ru adlf111
> ed@ggg.er fgdfgd1gd141

Причем для строки `"awlefla aaa@gmail.ru   adlf111 2 * ed@ggg.er    fgdfgd1gd141"` (два и более пробелов после адреса) рег. выражение работает как и задумано.
Пытался лучше изучить рег. выражения, но все равно не вижу, что тут не так.
Подскажите пожалуйста, где тут ошибка

IDE visual studio 2019
Стандарт ISO C++ 14

Comment: [регулярное выражение для почтовых адресов](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) (не поддерживает комментарии)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо экранировать в С++ косую черту Которая в регулярных выражениях экранирует точку:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::string emails = "awlefla aaa@gmail.ru adlf111 2 * ed@ggg.er fgdfgd1gd141";
    std::regex reg2("[a-z0-9_][a-z0-9_\\.-]*[a-z0-9_]@([a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9_-]*[a-z0-9]\\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,}");
    std::smatch matches;
    while (std::regex_search(emails, matches, reg2)) {
        std::cout << matches[0] << "\n";
        emails = matches.suffix().str();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Лучше использовать [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).